# SharePoint Office Online Server : New-OfficeWebAppsFarm Command

Tags: office-online-server, windows-server-2016

When I install Office online server on Windows 2016. After installing Prerequisites, I setup the OOS by command. The following error shows up. Does anyone have any idea on it.

I have installed The "Ink and Handwriting Services".

> PS C:\Users\Administrator.LITWAREINC> New-OfficeWebAppsFarm
>   New-OfficeWebAppsFarm : The operation failed. The server did not meet
>   the following prerequisites: - The "Ink and Handwriting Services"
>   Windows Server Feature must be installed and enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2016 doesn’t contain Ink And Handwriting Services, so omit that from the Add-WindowsFeature command. So, working script for WS2016 is:

```
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server,Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-WebServer,Web-Common-Http,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Static-Content,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression,Web-Security,Web-Filtering,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-App-Dev,Web-Net-Ext45,Web-Asp-Net45,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Includes,NET-Framework-Features,NET-Framework-Core,NET-HTTP-Activation,NET-Non-HTTP-Activ,NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45
```

[Source](https://blog.jussipalo.com/2017/05/office-online-server-on-windows-server.html)

Kindly have a look at the below links

1. [Office Online Server For SharePoint 2016](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/office-online-server-for-sharepoint-2016/)
2. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b91c1eea-a501-42fc-9a85-7c8eead1aa56/office-web-server-on-windows-server-2016-ink-and-handwiting-services?forum=SP2016
3. http://strangecodestuff.blogspot.com/2017/04/sharepoint-2013-office-web-apps-sever.html